# How can i redirect the whole path to HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have searched, but yet to find the answer.

I have a site for recipes, and all recipes go in path like this:

```
http://example.com/recipe/recipe-name
```

How can i redirect this whole path to HTTPS?

Right now i have only redirects to my homepage, that is working fine.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

**above code for non https & www redirect ==> https without www**